# Adding a custom attribute to a Wordpress theme's <html> tag programmatically or statically

Tags: wordpress, casting, chromecast, video.js

I am implementing the VideoJS Chromecast Plugin in my Wordpress site and, for the life of me, could not figure out how to add a custom attribute to the theme's `<html>`tag like so:

```
<html data-cast-api-enabled="true">
```

I have looked at the theme's wp-header.php and wp-page.php but I could not figure where I could insert this particular attribute. I would either do this programmatically with a script or statically typed in the PHP code. I am new to WP and I used to code my Joomla theme's index.php at will.

I have also installed the plugin's [example](https://github.com/kim-company/videojs-chromecast#configuration-example) and their demo index.html plays just fine with the Cast icon working with the VideoJS player instance. The only difference I can see using Chrome's built-in debugger is that the attribute is not set in the  tag and VideoJS responds with "Cast APIs not available. Retrying...". No other JS or CSS errors that I can see.

Does anyone have figured this out?

Many thanks!
Relativity

Answer (score 1):

Under "Appearance" on the left, then the "Editor", and then within the theme should be a plain "header.php" file which is literally the first section of html for every wordpress page.

It should look something like this:

```
<?php /**
 * The Header for this theme.
 * A bunch of theme info here
 */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Here is the first HTML tag for the page -->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<!--... more html and php code follows...-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zarazha for leading the way.

I happen to be using the X theme from Theme.co and it has 4 child themes. All the child themes reference the "global" or parent theme. I went to cat the parent's "_header.php" and found exactly the above.

To be more precise:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="no-js ie9" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>><!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

  <?php do_action( 'x_before_site_begin' ); ?>

  <div id="top" class="site">
```

Many thanks. StackOverflow is awesome!!! ;)